# Solving a recurrence with circles

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, circles

Consider n circles in the plane such that each intersects every other, and no three circles met at a point. I need to find a recurrence for the number of regions formed then solve the recurrence.

I started by diving the plane into rn regions. I then added a new circle and tried figuring out how many new regions that added to get an idea but struggle with the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this figure will help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Suppose you have an arrangement of $n$ circles, and you add a new circle, $C$. For each intersection point of $C$ with a previous circle, one of the previous regions will be split in two (if this is unclear, look at some small examples). Therefore, if $r_n$ is the number of regions, you have
$$
r_{n+1}=r_n+\text{# of intersections of $C$ with previous circles}.
$$
All that is left is to count the number of intersections.

Answer (score 0):

You can take cue from Venn diagram. Take this for $3$ circles as an example.

Every circle is getting divided into $3$ regions but only one region of each circle is not shared. So that gives you $3$ regions that are not shared.

Then the next $3$ are shared between each of the two circles.

The last one is shared among all of them and that is only one.

So while there are $3$ regions for each circle, there are only $7$ different regions in total.

Similarly for $4$ circles, you get $13$ different regions.

$a(1) = 1$

$a(2) = a(1) + 2 \times 1 = 3$

$a(3) = a(2) + 2 \times 2 = 7$

$a(4) = a(3) + 2 \times 3 = 13$

$a(n+1) = a(n) + 2n$

It translates to $n(n-1) + 1$ regions for $n$ intersecting circles.